# Is very word of the Vedas eternal according to advaita vedanta?

Tags: vedas

Advaita vedanta believes that vedas are eternal and authorless.

So do advaita vedanta believe that every single word of the Vedas is eternal and authoritative.(every verse of the Vedas is eternal)

Or it is just philosophy of the Vedas (karma, Moksha dharma)

Comment: The truths, the laws, of the vedas are eternal.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda can you give some scripture reffence to it from Advaita vedanta

Comment: Refer to Shankaracharya's Gita Bhasya on Gita 18.66 
Even Vedas arent infallible as per him

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru he doesn't say Vedas aren't infallible. He says if at all they contradict direct experience then they should be understood in a different context.

Comment: @MrGreenGold There is also the question of arthavada, gunavada and anuvada of the sentences in vedas. Mimansa, advaita and visishtadvaita have different interpretations of the same. All of them will agree that vedas are infallible but sentences have to be intrepreted properly. However, the truths and dharma in the vedas are eternal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on Sethu's comment, here is the Gita bhashya of Adi Shankara on verse 18.66,

> The validity of the Vedas holds good only with regard to matters
> concerning the relation between ends and means of Agnihotra etc.,
> whichare not known through such valid means of knowledge as direct
> perception; but not with regard to objects of direct perception etc.,
> because the validity of the Vedas lies in revealing what is beyond
> direct perception. Therefore it is not possible to imagine that the
> idea of egoism with regard to the aggregate of body etc., arising from
> an obviously false knowledge, is a figurative notion. Surely, even a
> hundred Vedic texts cannot become valid if they assert that fire is
> cold or non-luminous! Should a Vedic text say that fire is cold or
> non-luminous, even then one has to assume that the intended meaning of
> the text is different, for otherwise (its) validity cannot be
> maintained; but one should not assume its meaning in a way that might
> contradict some other valid means of knowledge or contradict its own
> statement.
>
> The Vedic texts enjoining rites (and duties) etc. are not invalid,
> because they, through the generation of successively newer tendencies
> by eliminating the successively preceding tendencies, are meant for
> creating the tendency to turn towards the indwelling Self.

We can also look at the [brahma sutra bhashya of Adi shankara 1.3.33](http://www.ibiblio.org/sripedia/ebooks/sbe34/sbe34102.htm)

> Let us examine, as an illustrative example, the injunctive passage,
> 'He who is desirous of prosperity is to offer to Vâyu a white animal.'
> All the words contained in this passage are directly connected with
> the injunction. This is, however, not the case with the words
> constituting the corresponding arthavâda passage, 'For Vâyu is the
> swiftest deity; Vâyu he approaches with his own share; he leads him to
> prosperity.' The single words of this arthavâda are not grammatically
> connected with the single words of the injunction, but form a
> subordinate unity of their own, which contains the praise of Vâyu, and
> glorify the injunction, only in so far as they give us to understand
> that the action enjoined is connected with a distinguished divinity.
> If the matter conveyed by the subordinate (arthavâda) passage can be
> known by some other means of knowledge, the arthavâda acts as a mere
> anuvâda, i.e. a statement referring to something (already known).
> When its contents are contradicted by other means of knowledge it acts
> as a so-called gunavâda, i.e. a statement of a quality. Where,
> again, neither of the two mentioned conditions is found, a doubt may
> arise whether the arthavâda is to be taken as a gunavâda on account of
> the absence of other means of knowledge, or as an arthavâda referring
> to something known (i.e. an anuvâda) on account of the absence of
> contradiction by other means of proof. The latter alternative is,
> however, to be embraced by reflecting people.--**The same reasoning
> applies to mantras also.**

Let us take a vedic sentence. Indra performed a yagna called X and because of this, he became powerful and was able to defeat Y in the battle of Z.

Now there can be multiple interpretations of the sentences. Some may believe that the battle of Z happened. Indra, X, Y, Z etc are all real. Some may interpret it to mean that if you do yagna X, you will become powerful to defeat enemies and this does not mean Z happened or there was a person Y.

Comment: So according to him vedas are not fully eternal and authoritative

Comment: @DarkKnight  It just means that all words should not be taken as such. Some may require interpretation. I have added stanzas from Brahma Sutra bhashya also.

Comment: so overall all verses in the Vedas are authoritative and eternal